# Deploy with iPhone Target only when Archiving

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, build, xcode4.5

I'm developing an app made for an iPhone, but would like to gradually support the iPad's screen.  However, it would be great if I could release the app via ad-hoc with the iPhone as a target, but develop it with universal support.

To be brief, I want to press Product --> Archive and get this:
[image: http://modmyi.com/images/anthony/dashboardmapipad1.png]

And get this when I press Product --> Run:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/3r9RP.png]

I tried editing the scheme, but there are no options available it seems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly what you are asking for but it should work:

- Copy your target
- Set one target to be iPhone and the other to Universal
- Have two schemes, one that uses the iPhone-only target, one that uses the Universal target
- Use the iPhone-only scheme for archiving, use the Universal scheme for development and debugging.

Comment: Funny, that's what I'm trying right now!  I'll accept this as the answer if it works.

Comment: It worked!  It was a bit of a pain getting the project name set to something besides "Project copy", but I got it.  Thanks a lot, Simon!

Comment: @cbh2000 yes, Xcode is really annoying about that.  The fact that you can't set the name of the copy when you make it is a real PITA to find all the spots where it sets things to "project copy"